# Error cannot infer argument type for a method in C#, telegrambot

Tags: c#, frameworks, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am having a lot of problems with my code. And how to fix it. *Please help me!!!*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;k
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Telegram.Bot;

namespace ChatBot
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static TelegramBotClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client = new TelegramBotClient("");

            client.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;

            client.StartReceiving();

            Console.WriteLine("Bot started. Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            client.StopReceiving();
        }

        private static void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Message.Text != null && e.Message.Text.ToLower() == "hello")
            {
                client.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Hello, " + e.Message.From.FirstName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The bugs I am getting are:**

- Error CS1061  'TelegramBotClient' does not contain a definition for 'StopReceiving' and no accessible extension method 'StopReceiving' accepting a first argument of type 'TelegramBotClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

-Error  CS0411  The type arguments for method 'TelegramBotClientExtensions.StartReceiving(ITelegramBotClient, ReceiverOptions?, CancellationToken)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

-Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MessageEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you talking about build errors or runtime errors?